# Oracle SQL trying to compare different dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two order dates with different formats that I'm trying to compare and I'm getting an 'invalid date' error. Date 1. Date_of_ORDER is Varchar and has this format - 20180119.   Date 2. ORDER_DT is Date and has this format - 2018/01/19 00:00:00. I run the following code and get the 'invalid date' error...

```
 SELECT T2.ORDER_ID, T2.ORDER_DT, T1.PRODUCTNAME, T1.DATE_OF_ORDER, T2.ORDER_DT
FROM FIRSTTABLE T1 INNER JOIN
     SECONDTABLE T2
     ON T1.ORDERID = T2.ORDER_ID AND TO_DATE(DATE_OF_ORDER, 'YYYY/MM/DD') = ORDER_DT
ORDER BY T2.ORDER_ID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally all dates should be placed in the appropriate datatype.  Sometimes you don't get a choice with third party apps etc.  Anyway, if you're stuck with dates stored as strings, then

1) Make sure you use the right format mask to get your data

```
SQL> create table t ( id int, d varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> insert into t values (1,'1999/01/01');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t values (2,'2005/04/08');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t values (3,'2012/09/21');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t values (4,'2018/11/19');

1 row created.

SQL> select id, to_date(d,'YYYYMMDD') from t;
select id, to_date(d,'YYYYMMDD') from t
                   *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

SQL>
SQL> select id, to_date(d,'YYYY/MM/DD') from t;

        ID TO_DATE(D
---------- ---------
         1 01-JAN-99
         2 08-APR-05
         3 21-SEP-12
         4 19-NOV-18

4 rows selected.
```

2) Even if you have the right format mask, because a string can hold anything, you till run the risk of getting errors, eg

```
SQL>
SQL> insert into t values (5,'2019/02/12');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t values (6,'20XX/11/19');   <=== problem

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t values (7,'2012/07/12');

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> select id, to_date(d,'YYYY/MM/DD') from t;
ERROR:
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string



no rows selected
```

If you are on a recent version of Oracle, you can use the extended syntax to either return a default value, or use VALIDATE_CONVERSION to eliminate from consideration the invalid date

```
SQL>
SQL> select id, to_date(d default null on conversion error,'YYYY/MM/DD'  ) from t;

        ID TO_DATE(D
---------- ---------
         1 01-JAN-99
         2 08-APR-05
         3 21-SEP-12
         4 19-NOV-18
         5 12-FEB-19
         6
         7 12-JUL-12

7 rows selected.

SQL>
SQL> select id, d
  2  from   t
  3  where validate_conversion(d as date,'YYYY/MM/DD') = 1;

        ID D
---------- --------------------
         1 1999/01/01
         2 2005/04/08
         3 2012/09/21
         4 2018/11/19
         5 2019/02/12
         7 2012/07/12

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Very interesting Conner. I'm confused has to how I will write my where statement to compare the two date with the conversion function

Comment: Obviously `TO_DATE(DATE_OF_ORDER, 'YYYY/MM/DD') = ORDER_DT` will not ever match if the string is an invalid date.  So you could write `TO_DATE(DATE_OF_ORDER default null on conversion error, 'YYYY/MM/DD') = ORDER_DT` 

If you're on an older version of Oracle, check here for options

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=equvivalent-function-for-isdate

Answer (score 1):

If the format is YYYYMMDD, why are you using slashes?

Try this:

```
TO_DATE(DATE_OF_ORDER, 'YYYYMMDD')
```

If your format is what you say, then this should work.

Note:  You should fix the data.  You have just wasted a bunch of time trying to fix a problem that never would have existed if the date were stored using a proper `date` data type.  It is that simple -- waste time or get work done.

Comment: Thanks so responding Gordon. When I run that, I get another error...ERROR:  Bad value 0 for year

Comment: @Shell . . . As I say, your data has problems.  Assuming you have values such as 000-01-01 to mean, say `NULL`, you can fix the problem.  But there could be other problems.